# PyPI: Module code doesn't update when I upload a new version

Tags: python, module, pypi

I created my first module, and released the first version 0.0.1. I then completed my todo list and added more functions and enhanced most of the old code, and tried to upload a new version (0.0.2). It took long but I finally did upload it.

I reinstalled it to get the latest version, and tried it. All the new functions didn't work, and it was basically the old code (0.0.1). I released new builds to try and fix the problem, but it wont work: "module 'modulename' has no attribute 'notify'"

I did `twine upload --skip-existing dist/*`, `pip --no-cache-dir install module` and tried to remove all files with that module name before installing it again, but it still had the old code. I downloaded the .tar.gz and went to the folder the `__init__.py` and the `module.py` files were, and the code was up to date.

Is it because of my computer, or is the code not updating? It's confusing, so I need help on this. Thanks

Comment: How long did you wait after the upload? The PyPI CDN can take some time to propagate new packages.

Comment: It updated instantly and when I used pip to install it, it said "Installed module==0.0.2.3"

Answer (score 0):

Are you rebuilding the distribution before you publish it with `twine`? You'll need to run something like:

```
python setup.py sdist bdist_wheel
```

every time you want to make a new release. This creates a new distribution file in the `dists` directory, which is what `twine` uploads to PyPI.